# INSERT INTO different tables

Tags: php, mysql

how i can insert in different tables of a database .
in php first i select database and after that i execute mysql string

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","usr","123");
mysqli_select_db($con,"mydb"); 
$myfilling=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

i try below code for `$sql`

```
INSERT INTO tbl_18 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...)  
INSERT INTO tbl_38 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...)  
INSERT INTO tbl_67 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...) 
INSERT INTO tbl_42 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...)  
INSERT INTO tbl_38 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...)
```

but it show's Error below
 for the right syntax to use near `'INSERT INTO tbl_67 ...'` what is wrong in my code

Comment: You'll have to show us the actual sql you are trying to execute.  BTW -- table names really should be far more descriptive for a developer's sanity.

Comment: Can you show exact code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mysqli_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) is only intended for one sql query at a time. Instead use [mysqli_multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) and separate each query by a semicolon.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","usr","123");
mysqli_select_db($con,"mydb"); 
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_18 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...);'.
       'INSERT INTO tbl_38 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...);'.
       'INSERT INTO tbl_67 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...);'.
       'INSERT INTO tbl_42 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...);'.
       'INSERT INTO tbl_38 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...);';
$myfilling = mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql);
```

Or you can break up the queries and execute them one by one.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","usr","123");
mysqli_select_db($con,"mydb");
mysqli_query($con,'INSERT INTO tbl_18 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...)');
mysqli_query($con,'INSERT INTO tbl_38 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...)');
mysqli_query($con,'INSERT INTO tbl_67 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...)');
mysqli_query($con,'INSERT INTO tbl_42 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...)');
mysqli_query($con,'INSERT INTO tbl_38 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( ...)');
```

Comment: which way is better for cpu usage and memory of system ?

Comment: mysqli_multi_query is better when handling multiple queries as it will only take one trip out to your database and back.